# Android App Widget Preview Style

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an app widget, 1 cell by 1 cell, with this XML file:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="60000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/my_appwidget"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
/>
```

When I browse widgets (Nexus 7, KitKat, but probably on other things as well) some other 1 x 1 widget previews have the widget itself, on the left, lifesize, and a magnified faint greyscale copy of it as a background. This is true for both built-in and installed apps.

That is the effect that I want, but I can't work out how to do it.

My preview image, and those for some other installed apps, just sit centered in the preview square, with no background. If I add my own shadow, the whole image gets scaled down - not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the effect I'm after is not to do with widgets at all, but shortcuts ( which also appear when you browse widgets. ) I found this out by looking at the ApiDemos sample, which has both a 1 cell widget and a shortcut. Shortcuts were introduced with API level 1, and they are now almost undocumented, it seems, so I presume they were supposed to be superseded by widgets.

Shame, because the visual effect is much nicer than  a plain image scaled down to leave space all around it.

It would be nice to achieve aesthetic consistency with the look of shortcuts in the widget browser, since there seem to be a fair number especially for Android built in stuff, but it looks as though that's not possible if you want widget functionality. Anyone know better?